# JQueryUI sortable issue on Chrome

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a list with about twenty items, and I use JqueryUI sortable to sort them by drag and drop functionality,
It works well on IE an Firefox but on Chrome when drag it up, the page scroll reversely and goes down,
I use Twitter Bootstrap for styling.
I was wondering if any body had a similar issue
My code is as below:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#sortable").sortable({
            update: function (event, ui) {
            }});
        $("#sortable").disableSelection();

    });
</script>
```

and my list uses ul and li tags

Comment: here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/25731tL9/ there is no chrome bug with the UI stuff... you should start debuging styling attributes and JS or plugins which might causes this issue

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem where the page was scrolling to the bottom in Chrome when I tried dragging a sortable item.
The fix I found was to add the `scroll: false option`, like this:

```
$( ".sortable" ).sortable({
           scroll: false
});
```

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31950520/jquery-ui-sortable-draggable-causing-window-jump) gave me the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem! I went through my css disabling different styles until I found what caused it. In my case I had set `overflow-y: scroll;` on my `<body>` tag. Moving it to the `<html>` tag solved my problem, unfortunately that caused the problem in Firefox instead..

In the end I removed the `overflow` property altogether. It wasn't so important to me.